# MVVMcross: Restore From Suspension or Pause

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I would like to launch a particular viewmodel...similar to ShowViewModel()... when the application comes back from suspension.

For an Android's activity, it seems like the current activity can be pause and I would need to have the call in the OnResume of each activity in the application.

For iOS, particularly iOS 7, it seems that the application will be resumed after a suspension and the call must would be in the appdelegate's WillEnterForeground().  In this scenario, I am assuming that the last ViewModel/View is unknown.

How is the best way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have OnResignActivation() and DidEnterBackground() on iOS in the app delegate. You should remember your current view model there and navigate back to it if the application is reactivated.

Comment: I'd suggest having a play with some basic apps. Suspension and termination are very different scenarios and you may want to handle them separately. For a starter on iOS life cycle, the xam docs provide a nice starting point http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_2_application_lifecycle_demo/

Comment: I guess the question is actually how to call a new viewmodel from a device-specific project?  How do you get a device-specific class to change to a different viewmodel?